# Are Firebase dependencies outdated in the Spanish website?

Tags: firebase

My question is about the Firebase docs.

I was just researching at Firebase to solve a question about dependencies, when I just figured out that, in the Spanish section of Firebase, the dependencies for Firebase are at `11.8.0`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?hl=es-419

but, if I research about Firebase database it will show me `15.0.0` (and the rest of dependencies need to be at least 15.0.0 too, like storage).

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

The only thing that seems updated to me are all the Google services dependencies.

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Is this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

That indeed looks outdated. Although all the information on that page will still work, it should have been updated like the English version.

Can you [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) or report it through the <kbd>ENVIAR COMENTARIOS</kbd> link on that page? I'll also file an internal report, just to be sure.